# How do I enter just one time in a socket.on()

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

Right now im trying to call a windows.print() inside a socket.on() using a button, the problem is when I press the button multiple times it keeps adding the previous call to the new one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGa8n.jpg

I already reached the expected result, but its clearly a hax:

```
socket.on('PrintAnswer',function(msg){
    let print= msg;
    if(print=== userId){
        windows.print();
    }
    console.log("Printing= "+ print);
    msg.end(); //  <--   Hax
});
```

The code breaks and works as intended, but im looking for a cleaner solution. Return did not help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I put the code outside the socket.on() and its working. Was searching for a cleaner way but it works.